# Listing all azure vm belonging to particular subnet

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-ise, azure-powershell

I want to list all azure vms in a particular subnet. I don't know how to write a PowerShell script for this. I am trying the below but it's not giving the desired output. My desired output- All VMs belonging to subnet having ip 10.87.00.01...10.87.99.99 should get listed in my text file subnet_VM.txt

```powershell
$tgtIP = "10.87.xx.xx"
$vms = Get-AzureVM

foreach($vm in $vms)
{
  $vmIP = (Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $vm.ServiceName  –Name  $vm.Name).IpAddress
  foreach($ip in $vmIP)
  {
    if($ip -like '$tgtIP*')
    {
       $vm.Name > C:\AZURE\subnet_VM.txt
    }
  }
}
```

It would be very helpful if I get help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it help if you just change this `$tgtIP = "10.87"`? At the moment you're trying to match an ip with `x.x` which will obviously never work

Comment: @arco44 -That also didn't work

Comment: You need to edit the question to **a)** describe desired output **b)** explain exactly what "doesn't work"

Comment: I tried $tgtIP = "10.87" as suggested by @arco044 and that didnt work. I have edited my desired output in the question part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in Azure the subnets have a name. So a more elegant solution would be to use a subnet name than the raw IP range. Since that is something you are ultimately trying to achieve, I am including that solution as well.

```
$vms = Get-AzureVM

$tgtSubnet = "Subnet-1"
foreach($vm in $vms)
{
    $thisVM = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $vm.ServiceName –Name $vm.Name
    $thisVMSubnet = Get-AzureSubnet -VM $thisVM
    if ($thisVMSubnet -eq $tgtSubnet)
    {
        $output  =$output + "`r`n" + $thisVM.Name 
    }
}
$output | Out-File C:\Azure\subnet_VM.txt
```

Comment: This script is currently no valid. The relevant script can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64258762/9931092