# List all the vm in a particular Subnet in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

Just wondering how to retrieve the VMs details in a given particular subnet in Azure.

I have used the below but it does not work anymore in powershell (Cloud shell)

[Listing all azure vm belonging to particular subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985282/listing-all-azure-vm-belonging-to-particular-subnet)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet has been tested against my environment :

```bsh
$vms = Get-AzVM

$tgtSubnet = "MySubnet"
foreach($vm in $vms)
{
    $networkInterface = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name ($vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id.Split('/')[-1])
    $subnetName = $networkInterface.IpConfigurations[0].Subnet.Id.split('/')[-1]

    if($subnetName -eq $tgtSubnet)
    {
        Write-Output $vm
    }
}
```

output:

[image]

Make sure [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.7.0) is installed on your machine.